# DDD Enity persistance scenario

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I'm trying to workout the best place to persist my domain changes. I've the following entities:

```
public class Period
{
   public Guid PeriodId { get; set; }
   public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
   public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}

Trade
{
   public Guid TradeId { get; set; }
   Trader Instigator { get; set; }
   Trader Acceptor { get; set; }
   Period period { get; set; }
   public long Volume { get; set; }
   public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Now for creating a new trade I've offloaded this to a Domain service

```
tradeService.PlaceTrade(Guid periodId, Guid UserId, decimal price. long volume)
```

The place trade functionality seems to fit nicely into the above domain service, the trade service persists the trade. I pass in an ITradeRepository class to facilitate.

To accept the trade I would like to have the following so that the domain logic for trade sits within the trade entity.

```
Trade trade = tradeRepository.Get(Guid tradeId)

TradeStatus = trade.Accept(userId);
```

The problem with the above is that the Trade entity is responsible for persisting the data and as such has a dependency to the ITradeRepository.

Is this the correct way of doing this? It feels dirty? Or work a better way be to create an extension method for the trade class to facilitate the same functionality for accepting a trade?

Any thoughts?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entities shouldn't know anything about the repositories. So the trade should accept the user id and set up its internal state to reflect it. But then the service or controller should then either add or save the trade to the repository. Saving the trade to the repository then persists the entity (and possibly many sub-entities that trade aggregates) in one go.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I was getting things confused. I envisions ddd domain service like creating an api so that you would make a single call to a domain objects method to perform an interaction. A bit like how the asp.net membership class works for the user object, user.changepassword. I've now realised that that functionality should be in the application layer in ddd.

Answer (score 3):

As Jack Hughes says, the entities shouldn't have a dependency on their repositories. Also, I don't see why you need a 'Service' to get your trade entity? This is the responsibility of repositories. Also not sure why you would pass a reference to the trade object to the get method?

This is how I'd code it:

```
   //This is an application service method    
    public void AcceptTrade(Guid tradeId, Guid acceptingTraderId)
    {
        using (IUnitOfWork unitOfWork = UnitOfWorkFactory.Create())
        {
            Trade trade = _tradeRepository.GetById(tradeId);
            Trader acceptingTrader = _traderRepository.GetById(acceptingTraderId);

            trade.Accept(acceptingTrader);

            _tradeRepository.Save(trade);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah you're right...sorry, ignoring that part. It was written in haste. Tradeservice.get() should of been a repository and also the trade reference should of been a guid. I'll amend this... Thanks for your suggestion of how to write it. That looks very clean!

Comment: Hi, may I ask you how the unitOfWork factory is been used in the context of the above code. Shouldn't the unitofwork be injected into the _tradeRepository constructor? I don't see how it's been used in the above? Thanks

Comment: Passing it to the repository is one way. I tend to use it in a passive way where the UoW gets set on the current thread, so it's available to the repositories in the current context. Similar to say, Thread.CurrentPrincipal where the current user performing the operation is always available.